# Execute Visual Fox Pro Commands from Java

Tags: java, visual-foxpro

I want to execute Visual Fox Pro Commands from my Java application. What is the best way to do so (preferably open source)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to talk to VFP data from a Java application, try using JDBC to connect to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the EXECSCRIPT() function in Visual Foxpro. it will allow you to call VFP commands and functions.

I assume that you can use JDBC and the Foxpro ODBC driver to connect to VFP. If so, you could make a call to the EXECSCRIPT() and pass in commands and functions.

```
   EXECSCRIPT("SELECT * FROM myTable")
```